# Ubuntu 12.10 Intel Ironlake Graphics Driver

Tags: graphics, intel, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and steam on my laptop. I need to install the Intel graphics driver. When I go into details on my system in says the graphics is unknown. Some Steam games will launch, I have had Splice, DEFCON and a few other small games working but when I launch Counter-Strike: Source or TF2 the audio plays but the screen is just black. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue issue with my Intel HD 3000 graphics. Eventually, I found out the Intel graphics don't support OpenGL 3.1 or the higher versions regarding the driver. Until something new is made or done, You kinda can't play those Steam games that require that graphics version to work on Intel HD graphics.